# How do I combine the results of two queries with ordering?

Tags: mysql, sql

How do you join the results of 2 queries, ordering by date?

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE tag='1'
SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE tag='3'
```

table1,table2 have the same fields:
`id|article|author|tag|date`

PS: BY THE WAY, tag IS `workid`

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use [`UNION ALL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) to get rows from both tables:

```
SELECT id, article, author, tag, date FROM table1 WHERE tag = '1'
UNION ALL
SELECT id, article, author, tag, date FROM table2 WHERE tag = '3'
ORDER BY date
```

---

You may also want to consider restructuring your database so that instead of using two tables you use just a single table with a field to distinguish the type of each row. Then the query can simplify to:

```
SELECT id, article, author, tag, date
FROM yourtable
WHERE (tag, type) IN (('1','type1'), ('3','type2'))
ORDER BY date
```

Answer (score 8):

```
SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT * 
        FROM   table1 
        UNION 
        SELECT * 
        FROM   table2) t 
ORDER  BY t.DATE
```

Comment: Code-only answers are low value on Stackoverflow because they do very little to educate/empower thousands of future researchers.