# how to combine 2 select statement and output results into 2 column

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables(basket_tb, vegetable_tb)
I want to check if a specific basket exist in basket_tb and if a specific vegetable exist in vegetable_tb. How to do it by combining my 2 select statement and output the result into 2 seperate columns.

```
SELECT basket_id FROM basket_tb WHERE basket_id = 2;
SELECT veg_id FROM vegetable_tb WHERE veg_id = 5;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I combine the results of two queries with ordering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5331808/how-do-i-combine-the-results-of-two-queries-with-ordering)

Comment: The union all output me the result 1 column only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting it to two rows you can use `UNION`, but only way to get those two as **columns** is to use `JOIN`. See below.

```
SELECT t1.basket_id, t2.veg_id
FROM 
(SELECT basket_id FROM basket_tb WHERE basket_id = 2) t1
JOIN
(SELECT veg_id FROM vegetable_tb WHERE veg_id = 5) t2
```