# How to get all rows from a table 1 using the specific matching row from table 1 and table 2

Tags: mysql, sql

I m trying to get all rows from table 1 using the specific matching row from table 1 and table 2 and then sort them as per date from table 1

Here's an example.

**Posts (table 1)**

| u_id | title | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | some | 19-07-2021 |
| 2 | some | 18-07-2021 |

**Follows (table 2)**

| u_id | r_u_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |

Now, let my **user_id = 2**.

I m trying to get all the columns in `posts` (table 1) WHERE its **u_id** matches with **u_id** of `follows` (table 2) where its **r_u_id** is user_id I defined, along with all the columns in `posts` (Table 1) where **u_id** is **user_id** I defined ordered by date from `posts` (table 1)

Here's the code I have tried so far:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
  posts 
  LEFT JOIN follows ON posts.u_id = follows.u_id 
WHERE 
  follows.r_u_id = '$user_id' 
  AND posts.category = '$u_category' 
  AND posts.language = '$u_language' 
  AND posts.status = 'Live' 
ORDER BY posts.date";
```

The above query works perfectly fine by returning all the columns in the posts (Table 1) where the **u_id** matches with **u_id** of follows (table 2) where its **r_u_id** is user_id I defined.

But it doesn't return the columns where **u_id** is **user_id** I defined, so I added this `posts.u_id = '$u_id'` as below.

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
  posts 
  LEFT JOIN follows ON posts.u_id = follows.u_id 
WHERE 
  follows.r_u_id = '$user_id' 
  AND posts.u_id = '$user_id' 
  AND posts.category = '$u_category' 
  AND posts.language = '$u_language' 
  AND posts.status = 'Live' 
ORDER BY posts.date";
```

And now it returns nothing.

I don't understand, as I already have a where clause mentioned returning the specific language and specific category from posts table, but why it doesn't work if I add another clause with **u_id** is my **user_id**.

The desired output I should be getting from the query I need should be **Every column in posts (Table 1)** listed above.

**Cause**, The **LEFT JOIN** of **follows ON posts.u_id = follows.u_id** will get me the columns from the posts (Table 1) that matches the u_id of posts (Table 1) with u_id of follows (Table 2) with the condition of r_u_id of my user_id, so it will get the column #1 from posts (Table 1),
However, as I also mentioned the where clause as `posts.u_id = '$u_id'`, it will also get column #2 from posts (Table 1) as well.

so the desired output will look like the below table.

**Desired output :**

| u_id | title | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | some | 18-07-2021 |
| 1 | some | 19-07-2021 |

Comment: @MeysamAsadi we already have sample data. But yes an exact table showing the desired output would be very useful.

Comment: You have clearly described: "I m trying to get all the columns in posts (table 1) WHERE its u_id matches with u_id of follows" **and** "all the columns in posts (Table 1) where u_id is user_id I defined". Did you manage to get this two datasets individually? Then [How do I combine the results of two queries with ordering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5331808/how-do-i-combine-the-results-of-two-queries-with-ordering)

Comment: From the sample data r_u_id and u_id are different, so you won't ever have an instance where both r_u_id and u_id equal the same value. I think you are looking to return the values if either are a match in this case you need to modify the where clause to be OR instead of AND.

WHERE 
  (follows.r_u_id = '$u_id' 
  OR posts.u_id = '$u_id')
  AND posts.category = '$u_category' 
  AND posts.language = '$u_language' 
  AND posts.status = 'Live'

Comment: What is the value of $ u_id in the condition posts.u_id = '$ u_id'? Is equal to 1 gives the desired result!

Comment: If `$u_id` is `2` then clearly adding `posts.u_id = '$u_id'` will cause it to never return any rows because according to your sample data, there is only one row in follows, which has u_id 1 and r_u_id 2. This means that `follows.r_u_id = '$u_id' ` restricts the results to only rows which have r_u_id 2, and because the row in posts with u_id 2 doesn't join to that row, it cannot be output. Therefore if you also specify `posts.u_id = '$u_id` then this means there are no longer any rows (taking into account the join) which meet all the criteria.

Comment: Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c95e44cc7d4110c8348ef8e768a01857 - removing the clauses pertaining to columns you haven't shown, and hard-coding the $u_id value it's much easier to see why your stated logic doesn't work. (I added a 3rd and 4th query to make the comparison clearer). Remember that the WHERE clause evaluates _each row individually_ to ensure it meets _all_ the criteria. Adding an "AND" doesn't mean "and all the other rows which meet this criteria", it means "and each row must meet this criteria plus all the others". An OR however, allows for alternative criteria

Comment: use UNION ALL . join the post table once to the first column and once to the second column and UNION ALL the result. demo in db<>fiddle : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=98f2cc94a72772a0bb65867d652ba4b9